# Mongodb - Query MultiKey Indexed Documents

Tags: mongodb, indexing, multikey

My question is about the way MongoDB operates when querying MultiKey document.

Assuming I have these documents:

`{
  a: 1,
  b: 2,
  c: ['x','y','z']
},
{
  a:3,
  b: null,
  c: ['x','z']
}`

My query is this:

`db.<collection>.find({ b: null, c: 'x'})`

And my index is:

`db.<collection>.ensureIndex({ c: 1 })`

My question is: For the query above (that asks for `c` AND `b`), how does MongoDB invokes the query? Does it 'see' that I have an index on `c` or does it try to only look for an index for both `c` AND `b` ?

Comment: use .explain() method after find() and look at nscannedObjects and nscanned. it helps you to check usage of index

Comment: Just did that... and nscannedObjects is the size of the collection. Why does it go through the entire collection just to get something by an indexed field.

Comment: I made a test case for myself based on your docs and for searching in 2 docs, I got nscanned = 1, means it uses the indexing. look at cursor in .explain() and if it using the index, the cursor should be something like "BtreeCursor c_1"

Comment: Cool. It works now. Probably it takes time to index large collections.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Disposer

The query just finds the index of `c` even if the statement includes `c` and `b`.